# React Native set up Android in MacOs

Tags: macos, react-native

Following the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup), I see I have to add the next paths to `.bash_profile`.

[image]

I have done it but I cannot find any folder named `tools` in the `sdk` folder:

What is wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloads tools in android studio SDK manager->
[image]

Comment: Thanks Shahid. That is the answer.

For some reason, the docs do not mention this package.